# How to fetch all the nodes and child nodes of JSON object in java?

Tags: java, json

I want to fetch all the nodes of the below JSON object. For example
result, identification, payment etc.

```
{
    "result": {
        "identification": {
            "transactionid": "Merchant Assigned ID",
            "uniqueid": "d91ac8ff6e9945b8a125d6e725155fb6",
            "shortid": "0000.0005.6238",
            "customerid": "customerid 12345"
        },
        "payment": {
            "amount": "2400",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "descriptor": "order number"
        },
        "level": 0,
        "code": 0,
        "method": "creditcard",
        "type": "preauthorization",
        "message": "approved",
        "merchant": {
            "key1": "Value1",
            "key0": "Value0"
        }
    },
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

I have used the following code:

```
JSONObject partsData = new JSONObject(returnString);
Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String result=iterator.next();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

But the result I am getting is:

```
id
result
jsonrpc
```

How do I get all the node names?

Comment: You just iterate over the first level of keys, but your key "result" is pointing to another `JSONObject` containing another level of keys.

Comment: If you need to parse multiple things in your json I recommend using jackson library.

Answer (score 1):

Move your iterator logic (to iterate over json) in a method
e.g.,

```
public Map<String,String> parse(JSONObject json , Map<String,String> out) throws JSONException{
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next();
        String val = null;
if ( json.getJSONObject(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
    JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject(key);
    parse(value,out);
} 

else {
     val = json.getString(key);
}


        if(val != null){
            out.put(key,val);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

This way you can check for each sub node in the json object.

Comment: It would be better to use an instanceof check where trying to get the sub-JSONObject; it is not nice to use Exception in a normal control flow.

Comment: I would consider typechecking as a much nicer option than working with intended exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried with your answer but i am getting an exception .                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: Kindly look at the earlier answer provided by me in the edit link. Ideally you should not be getting this exception cause there is an instance of check to avoid the try catch block (see the previous version of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse through all the objects.

```
JSONObject partsData = new JSONObject("result"); 

JsonObject identification = partsData.getJsonObject("identification");

JsonObject payment = partsData.getJsonobject("payment");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vinay. But i don't want to hardcode node name in my code .It should be dynamic. My code should accept any JSONObject and get me the nodes.Is that possible?